# Two functions intersect,solve the equation.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Given two functions,show where they intersect

$(x^2−5)^2/(x+7)^2=\sqrt{169-x^2}$

I have already tried to square both of them but I get a very complex equation and I can not solve it. I saw a guy who put Ln before and before the two sides of the equation.

Comment: guys, should Natural logarithm is aplied herre

Comment: You didn't provide two functions; you gave one equation.  Do you mean to say the first function is $(x^2-5)^2/(x+7)^2$ and the second function is $\sqrt{169-x^2}$?

Comment: yea, dude if you speak spanish let me know, its difficult to explain with English

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak Spanish.  [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=intersection+of+%28x^2%E2%88%925%29^2%2F%28x%2B7%29^2+and+sqrt{169%E2%88%92x^2}) says there are two intersections: $x\approx -3.96135$ and $x\approx 7.19026$.

Comment: ok dude, but do you think that applying natural logarithm is ok?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet.  Do you know the [laws of logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities)?  Use these to try to get the logarithms of both sides of the equations; see if you get a simpler expression.

Comment: ok i will do what i can thank you verymuch

Comment: Your equation is a 8th-degree polynomial.  There is no simple solution for such equations.  See [How to solve an nth degree polynomial equation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200617/how-to-solve-an-nth-degree-polynomial-equation).

Comment: dude and do you agree with taking Natural Logarithm?, should i move this question to another section ?

Comment: Natural logarithms will not help.  I suggest you make sure that the equation you have written is correct.

Comment: Can you explain me why natural logarithms will not help?,

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, what topic is it about?  Does your class allow the use of graphing calculators?  If so, then perhaps that would be the way to answer this question.

Comment: diferential calculus, but we are supposed to do it without graphs

Comment: Are you required to plot their graphs and find number of solutions?

Comment: Because at best you will get something like $$ 4\left[\ln(x-\sqrt{5}) + \ln(x+\sqrt{5})- \ln(x+7)\right] = \ln(13-x) + \ln(13+x)$$ which cannot be solved without numerical methods.

Comment: well we want it without graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation simplifies to an 8th degree polynomial that can't be solved explicitly. Applying logarithms gives you $2 \log(x^2 - 5) - 2 \log(x+7) = \frac{1}{2} \log(169-x^2)$, but this does not simplify. As always, numerical approximations such as newton's method will get you approximate answers that @JoelReyesNoche gave.

Comment: ok it seems like it is the answer , thank you @JoelReyesNoche, and you qwr, so in conclusion you take natural logarithm . Do you know   a good book for this topic, i have Stewart´s Precalculus, but it doesn´t explain it well

Comment: You're welcome.  But the conclusion is *not* to take natural logarithms; the solution is to use numerical approximations.