# What are special cases of polynomials of degree ≥ 5?

Tags: polynomials

What are all polynomials of degree ≥ 5 that have solution formulas?
Numerical methods like calculating for each number is not what I ask for.

The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/200622/293694) states:

> Note that for some special cases (e.g., $x^n - a$), solution formulas
>   exist, but they do not generalize to all polynomials. In fact, it is
>   known that only a very small part of polynomials of degree $\ge 5$ admit
>   a solution formula using the operations listed above.

The other [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1121529/293694) in the same [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200617/how-to-solve-an-nth-degree-polynomial-equation) states:

> There are general formulas for the general equations
>   $x^n-x+t=0$
>   and
>   $ax^{2\mu}+bx^\mu-x^\nu+c=0$

Comment: xn-axn-a is unreadable. Please go to the help menu, and study up on how to format math on this website.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I feel sorry, but I added a link to the answer. I hope it is enough as I can't fix it right now, but I will try to fix it.

Comment: I don't want a link, I want a properly formatted question that I can read. Can *you* read xn-axn-a? How can you expect anyone else to. If worst comes to worst, write it out in words.

Comment: Obviously, $ax^n+b=0$ is solvable, as is $ax^6+bx^3+c=0$ or $ax^6+bx^4+cx^2+d=0$

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I can't fix now, because I don't know how to format, but I am already reading the reference to fix it. Is the question understandable?

Comment: I'll ask you again – can **you** understand xn-axn-a? If you can't, how do you expect me to?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I have fixed. I asked if the question itself understandable. Let me know if something is still wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, do you mean numerical methods or solution formulas by saying "solvable"? Because any polynomial is solvable, but I need those that have solution formulas like those with degree $\le 4$, if you mean the latter, then I need a list of all polynomial or understand how to know which one has a solution formula and what is the solution formula.

Comment: I mean analytical solution. I don't think it is possible to establish an exhaustive list.

Comment: @Yves Daoust, I am not sure what exactly "analytical solution" means, but I guess it is solving by guessing options, i.e. neither of the 2 given options. I understand your last sentence as among many polynomials we can find ones with solution formulas, but to find them all we need to scan all the possible polynomials and we will be finding them as long as we scan them. I thought there are a few of them with solution formulas, but your idea is a bit different. By anyway, I got what mean.

Comment: @ZiyaCeferov: there are too many possibilities (infinitely many) to be able to give an exhaustive list. You need to read about Galois' theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#Application_to_classical_problems

Comment: I don't believe there is a general formula for solving $x^n-x-t=0$ in radicals, not even for the case $n=5$. Dummit has written a paper on solving solvable quintics; it's at http://www.cem.uvm.edu/~ddummit/quintics/solvable.pdf