# Is there a way to solve $ c\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{(1+g)^i}{(1+r)^i}=v $ for $g$?

Tags: polynomials

Is there a way to solve the following for $g$?

$$
c\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{(1+g)^i}{(1+r)^i}=v
$$

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200617/how-to-solve-an-nth-degree-polynomial-equation) there is no general easy answer as it is a 10th degree equation but I was still wondering if you could share some idea for this specific case. [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=c%20*%20Sum%20%281%2Bx%29%5Ei%20%2F%20%281%2Br%29%5Ei%2C%20i%3D1%20to%2010%20%3D%3D%20v%20%26%26%20c%20%3E%200%20%26%26%20v%20%3E%200%20%26%26%20x%20%3E%200%20%26%26%20r%20%3E%20-1) might also be helpful.

Comment: I think there's a geometric series in there somewhere. I'm too rusty to confirm it so someone else, take over please.

Comment: While this can be simplified, using geometric series, that doesn't really make it solvable.  Letting $\lambda = \frac {1+g}{1+r}$, your sum is $\lambda\times \frac {\lambda^{10}-1}{\lambda-1}$ so your equation becomes $c\lambda(\lambda^{10}-1)
=\nu(\lambda-1)$  Or $c\lambda^{11}-(\nu+c)\lambda+\nu=0$  which, while, simpler looking, is still a pretty general degree $11$ polynomial.

Comment: What is the background of your question? Do you want a closed form of the solution? Or a way to find numerical approximations? I imagine that this is coming from finance?